# xWalkWebView while loading page?

Tags: android, webview, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk, crosswalk-project

I am working with `xWalkWebView`

and I would like to know the equivalent to this code

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            // progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            // progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view,
                    HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {


        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks using Crosswalk, you can also ask question by sending email to

crosswalk-help@lists.crosswalk-project.org

***For this question:***

```
  mXWalkView.setUIClient(new XWalkUIClient(mXWalkView) {
        @Override
        public void onPageLoadStarted(XWalkView view, String url) {
            System.out.println("onPageLoadStarted  " +url);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageLoadStopped(XWalkView view, String url, 
                    LoadStatus status) {
            System.out.println("onPageLoadStopped  " + status);
        }
    });

  mXWalkView.setResourceClient(new XWalkResourceClient(mXWalkView) {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(XWalkView view, 
                    XWalkHttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
            System.out.println("onReceivedHttpAuthRequest");
        }
    });
```